# как исправить ошибку в pyowm NotFoundError

Tags: python, telebot, pyowm

Тут приведён мой код, который работает нормально.
[image: работает как надо]
Выводит города, вроде бы всё нормально, но проблема в том, что бот будет работать корректно, если города будут написаны правильно, в ином случае он выдаёт ошибку `NotFoundError`.
[image: выводит ошибку]
Пробовал через `try`, но не помогло(

```
import telebot
import logging
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

owm = OWM('api')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('api', config_dict)
client = telebot.TeleBot("api")


@client.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def start_bot(message):
    help_comm = "Для того чтобы узнать погоду в том или ином городе введите его название.\nВАЖНО пиши названия городов правильно, а то я могу отключиться"
    client.send_message(message.chat.id,help_comm)

@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_bot(message):
    start = f"<b>Добро Пожаловать {message.from_user.first_name}!</b>\n Для того чтобы узнать погоду в том или ином городе введите его название:"
    client.send_message(message.chat.id,start,parse_mode='html')

@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_answer(message):
   try:
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
   except NotFoundError:
        mute = ("Хм такого города не существует")
    w.wind()
    w.humidity
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
    answer += "Температура сейчас " + str(temp) + "°C." + "\n\n"

    if temp < -5:
        answer += "На улице сильный мороз, одевайся тепло "
    elif temp < 0:
        answer+="На улице мороз, одевайся тепло ."
    elif temp < 10:
        answer+="Как-то прохладно, одевайся потеплее ."
    elif temp < 17:
        answer+= "Температура приемлимая, но одеться стоит ."
    else:
        answer+= "Температура отличная одевайся во что хочешь ."
    client.send_message(message.chat.id,answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.polling( none_stop = True )

try:
   observation = mgr.weather_at_place("") 
except NotFoundError: 
   print('error NotfoundError') 
   mute = ()
```

Comment: Не видно,  что через try пробовал.

Comment: try:
 observation = mgr.weather_at_place("")
except NotFoundError:
 print('error NotfoundError')
 mute = ()

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править", добавь этот код туда, где он должен быть.

Answer (score 2):

Блок try..except должен быть в том месте, где возникает ошибка, а не просто в каком-то месте, куда пришлось. В вашем коде он должен быть в функции  `send_answer(message)`.